# Setting a image to a radio button - preventing garbage collector from deleting image reference

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a multiple frame quiz app and a problem with adding an image to a `Radiobutton` widget, next to some text. I have removed the parts of code that had nothing to do with the image of the radio buttons, but I do have a working application otherwise, as well as working radio buttons. The problem is the images are shown next to text (as wanted) only once and when I create another frame and call `create_radio_button`s again, I get an error saying:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 1330, in configure
>       return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 1321, in _configure
>       self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
>   _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

I have tried doing this:

```
def create_radio_buttons(self):
    photo = PhotoImage(file="wrong.gif")
    self.photo_reference = photo
    R = ttk.Radiobutton(self, compound="left", # for image justification
                        text=possible_answer,
                        image=photo))
```

and:

```
def create_radio_buttons(self):
    R = ttk.Radiobutton(self, compound="left", # for image justification
                        text=possible_answer,
                        image=PhotoImage(file="wrong.gif")))
```

and also setting the image in a different class:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="wrong.gif")
self.photo_reference = photo
```

and then creating the button in the class to which the method create_radio_buttons belongs to.

I get the same result every time.

I will have to set the image later in the code, not in the initialization process so I have also tried setting it like this:

```
for radio_button in self.radio_buttons:
    radio_button.configure(image = self.quiz_reference.wrong_photo)
```

In this case my app crashes and I get this message:

> 2017-05-17 11:03:35.838 Python[19273:1316924]
>   CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL
>   which has no scheme

I suspect the former error is caused by the fact that `Python` frees memory every now and then and deletes the image, resulting in not being able to find it anymore. However I do not understand how I should avoid this (if this is the problem). I thought setting an additional reference will prevent it from being deleted but it apparently does not.

I would be very grateful for any help because I am about to lose my mind here.

**EDIT:** Below I have added my minimal working example. There is still quite a lot of code but without those things I think you wouldn't be able to see what the problem is.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

class Quiz(Tk):
    frames = {}
    number_of_questions = 5
    question_count = 0
    number_of_all_questions = 20 # per subject in SUBJECTdata.txt

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Tk.wm_title(self, "Quiz")

        self.wrong_photo = PhotoImage(file="wrong.gif")

        self.initialize_container_frame()
        self.initialize_start_page()

    def initialize_container_frame(self):
        self.container = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack()

        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def initialize_start_page(self):
        start_page = StartPage(self.container, self)
        start_page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[0] = start_page
        self.show_frame()

    def show_frame(self):
        if self.question_count <= self.number_of_questions:
            frame = self.frames.get(self.question_count, None)
            if frame != None: frame.tkraise()
            self.question_count += 1

    def set_subject(self):
        self.create_random_questions()
        self.show_frame()

    def create_random_questions(self):
        random_question_numbers = []
        table_of_possible_question_numbers = list(range(1, self.number_of_all_questions + 1))
        # here I just let it choose random question numbers
        while len(random_question_numbers) < self.number_of_questions:
            rand_number = random.choice(table_of_possible_question_numbers)
            random_question_numbers.append(rand_number)

            table_of_possible_question_numbers.remove(rand_number)

        # load the questions:
        question_count = 1
        for number in random_question_numbers:
            question = Question(self.container, self, number)
            self.frames[question_count] = question
            question_count += 1
            question.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class StartPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, quiz_reference):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.quiz_reference = quiz_reference

        self.show_frame()

    def show_frame(self):
        ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page stuff.\n\n\nChoose the subject:").pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Geography", command= lambda: self.quiz_reference.set_subject()).pack()



class Question(Frame):
    possible_answers = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"] # I am otherwise reading those from a file
    radio_buttons = []

    def __init__(self, parent, quiz_reference, number):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.number = number
        self.quiz_reference = quiz_reference
        self.create_radio_buttons()

    def create_radio_buttons(self):
        self.radio_buttons = []
        for possible_answer in self.possible_answers:
            R = ttk.Radiobutton(self,
                            compound="left",
                            text=possible_answer,
                            command=self.show_confirm_button)
            self.radio_buttons.append(R)
            R.pack()

    def show_confirm_button(self):
        self.confirm_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Confirm",
                                    command=self.change_text_on_confirm_button)
        self.confirm_button.pack(pady=8, side="bottom")
        self.is_confirm_button_showing = True

    def change_text_on_confirm_button(self):
        self.confirm_button.destroy()

        for radio_button in self.radio_buttons:
            radio_button.configure(state=DISABLED)
            radio_button.configure(image = self.quiz_reference.wrong_photo)
            # I will be checking which one is wrong later,
            # for now I just want to see it setting the image works

        ttk.Button(self, text="Next", command=self.quiz_reference.show_frame).pack()


app = Quiz()
app.mainloop()
```

With this I get to the third frame where I get the message that `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme` (this is where `tkinter` should add that image).

Please try to run the code for yourself.

This is a screenshot of the point on which I get the error:

[image]

As you can see, the image does get displayed but as a white square. I still think this is because Python garbage collector deletes it, but how do I prevent it from doing so?

I tried adding

```
self.wrong_photo2 = self.wrong_photo
```

after creating the image, with no success (the same exact problem).

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a minimal executable example? In this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251161/tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage3-doesnt-exist the problem had nothing to do with the gif or image but with the fact that tkinter.Tk() was instantiated more than once.

Comment: I added it to the post, please try to run the code and see how it works for you.

Comment: In Python 3.6 I could not reproduce the error (I used some random gif).

Comment: Thank you! I will try with different gif's (although I have tried this with 4 different ones already, but they were all edited in the same editing program). Maybe the program corrupts them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the radiobutton is not happy with being disabled *and* having an image. If I remove `radio_button.configure(state=DISABLED)` then the image works. A workaround which seems to work is to replace `state=DISABLED` with `command=(lambda: None)`, i.e.:

```
radio_button.configure(image=self.quiz_reference.wrong_photo,
                       command= (lambda: None))
```