# tkinter bitmapimage "image doesn't exist"

Tags: python-3.x, bitmapimage, tkinter-canvas

So I had it working, not sure what I changed but maybe someone else can take a peek and see where the error is.

here is the code the image is made and set to display in

```
def app_openfile(self, w, o, s):
    io_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    self.hex_data=Util.openFile(io_file)
    self.all_bin_data = Util.convertToBinary(self.hex_data)
    self.bin_data = self.all_bin_data
    ##infor bar call goes here
    self.bit_image = Util.makeImage(self.bin_data, w, o, s)
    print(self.bit_image.size)
    print(self.bit_image)
    self.photo = ImageTk.BitmapImage(self.bit_image, background='white')
    print(self.photo)
    self.binViewBox.create_image((0,0), image=self.photo, anchor=N)
    self.binViewBox.config(xscrollincrement=self.Scale,
                           yscrollincrement=self.Scale,
                           scrollregion=(0,
                                         0,
                                         math.ceil((int(w) * int(self.Scale))),
                                         math.ceil(len(self.binData)/int(w)* int(self.Scale))))
```

Now in the Util.makeimage bit, I have it set to show before it returns to verify it makes an image, and it does. But for some reason I haven't figured out yet, is why its now throwing this error.

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage11" doesn't exist
```

this is the return of the print statement before the exception is thrown

```
making image 1000 0 1

(1000, 96)

"PIL.Image.Image image mode=1 size=1000x96 at 0xE1ADD30"

pyimage11
```

EDIT:

this is an example what it should produce, but isn't pushed to the tkinter canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U1Wu.jpg)

Update as of 08/14/2018

```
def app_openfile():
    io_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    h_data=Util.openFile(io_file)
    all_b_data = b_data = Util.convertToBinary(h_data)
    all_b_data = b_data = Util.convertToBinary(h_data)
    viewtest = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500,bd=0)
    bimage = Util.makeImage(b_data, 800, 0, 5)
    bimage = ImageTk.BitmapImage(bimage)
    viewtest.create_image((0,0), image=bimage)
app_openfile()
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('PyDMT')
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Took out the class stuff to see if that was the issue, but still throws error.

Comment: You should use PhotoImage instance as an image value. rather then using BitmapImage Also, you need to keep the reference of your image.

im = Image.open(pathToImage)
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

Comment: Using BitmapImage because its type '1', this is to help with loading the size of the image, since many are quite large, and a normal Photoimage takes a long time for it to be created. The self.image, self.photo is used to keep reference. The image is made only from memory, there isn't a photo. The program pulls from files.

Comment: I think this might be useful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251161/tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage3-doesnt-exist/20259317

Comment: I am finding it seems to be with the .create_image bit. Thanks for the suggestions Mr J.

Comment: I had also tried it with PhotoImage, pushes the same error.