# How to add background as images to multiple windows linked to a single project using label

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add an image as background to my windows in Tkinter Python which are interlinked to each other using buttons. When I run the code by default my first window opens with image and on pressing the button to another window it opens as well, but when I press the back button to first window it gives me `pyimage3 does not exists` error.

[tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251161/tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage3-doesnt-exist)

I have tried the solutions posted on above link but none worked for me.

```
from tkinter import *


def win1():

    global window1
    global window2

    def goto2():
        window1.withdraw()
        win2()

    window1=Tk()
    window1.title('Window1')
    window1.geometry('300x300')


    img1=PhotoImage(file='wood.png')
    l1=Label(window1,image=img1,width=160,height=300)

    l1.image = img1

    l1.place(x=0,y=0)


    b=Button(window1,text='go to 2',command=goto2)
    b.pack()
    window1.mainloop()


def win2():
    global window2
    global window1

    def goto1():
        window2.withdraw()
        win1()



    window2=Toplevel()
    window2.title('Window2')
    window1.geometry('300x300')

    img2=PhotoImage(file='for.png')
    l2=Label(window2,image=img2,width=160,height=300)
    l2.image = img2

    l2.place(x=0,y=0)


    b1=Button(window2,text='go to  1',command=goto1)
    b1.pack()
    window2.mainloop()


win1()
```

error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Among other things, the way you're switching windows is broken. Suggest you use a different architecture, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028) for one alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use a different approach as martineau suggested, but yours can also work with two minor changes.

Firstly, you don't have to call `window2.mainloop()` as you are using `Toplevel`.

Secondly, since you called `withdraw` on your `window1` - just use `deiconify()` to recall it back.

```
def win2():
    global window2
    global window1

    def goto1():
        window2.destroy()
        #win1()
        window1.deiconify()


    window2=Toplevel()
    window2.title('Window2')
    window1.geometry('300x300')

    img2=PhotoImage(file='clear.png')
    l2=Label(window2,image=img2,width=160,height=300)
    l2.image = img2

    l2.pack()


    b1=Button(window2,text='go to  1',command=goto1)
    b1.pack()
    #window2.mainloop()
```