# Opening tkinter file from another tkinter file as a module

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module

I have created two Tkinter GUI files and I want to open the second file with the first one by the click of a button. I have made a function which just imports the second file but it is not working. Here's the code:

```
def receiver_func():

    exec(open('receiver.py').read()) #None of them is working and raising error
    import receiver
```

meanwhile, if I open both files individually, they run fine and smooth!

Here's the error log:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PAKLAP.pk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Programming Projects/Investors Foundation/main.py", line 16, in receiver_func
    exec(open('receiver.py').read())
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PAKLAP.pk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\PAKLAP.pk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist
```

Comment: I think the issue is with something else, As it works perfectly for me. And the `import` is not even needed

Comment: Don't use too many `Tk()` instances at the same time.

Comment: there is only one in the other file and two in the main file, one for the splash screen and one for the home screen

Comment: it had worked fine for me too in my previous projects where I just simply imported one file from the main file. but this one is being a nuisance

Comment: Yes,that's what I said,the first one window should be `Tk()`,others should be `Toplevel()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, brothers. The problem has been solved!

Comment: Your problem resembles the one described in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251161/tkinter-tclerror-image-pyimage3-doesnt-exist

Comment: Help appreciated Amna Javed, this one was being headache for me for several days!
Thanks a bulk ^_^.